# How do third party jar to exe conversion affects software

Tags: java

sorry if it feels a noobish question. My doubt is, if I converted a `jar` file to `.exe` file using software, such as **exe4j** or **launch4j**, will it still require a JRE enabled system to be able to run it, or will it just run like normal windows executable?

Also, I wanted to know if there is any other way to convert `jar` files to `exe` without using 3rd party software, also, are there any side effects of converting a `jar` program to `exe`.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the wrapper you plan to use?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it needs a JRE, these tools just make it possible to run Java applications more easily on Windows. The application itself is still a Java application, it is just wrapped in a launcher.

I myself would just create a batch file to start the application (or write a few-line simple application with the single task of starting the *jar*).

**Update:** exe4j and launch4j can embed a JRE.